# ActiveRecord inconsistent behavior?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 7 application, with a user model. I am experimenting with the console.

I have a User model, with only one record in it:

```
{"id":"1, "email":"me@myemail.com"}
```

I started a console session:

```
rails c
```

Then I did:

```
user = User.find(1)
```

Which gave me:

```
irb(main):009:0> user = User.find(1)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, email: "me@myemail.com", created_at: "2022-04-04 12:32:14.000515000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-04-04 12:32:14.000515000 +0000">
```

irb(main):010:0>

Then I did:

```
irb(main):010:0> user.nil?
```

And the response was:

```
=> false
```

Then I did:

```
user = User.find(2)
```

And the result was:

```
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
```

/installs/ruby/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.2.2/lib/active_record/core.rb:284:in `find': Couldn't find User with 'id'=2 (ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

Then I did:

```
user.nil?
```

And I was expecting the result to be true, instead I got:

```
=> false
```

Why?

Comment: This is not the least bit unexpected if you just remember that exceptions are supposed to immediately halt the execution of the code. That's kind of the whole point.  Use `find_by(id: 2)` if you want nil instead of an exception in the case of a missing record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you said:

```
user = User.find(2)
```

`find` raised an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception so the assignment never happens and `user` doesn't change. If you look at `user` here you'll see that it is what `User.find(1)` gave you.